# PowerShell foreach filter

Tags: powershell, passwords, office365

I try to develop incremental password change PowerShell script that goes like this

input csv file: D:\pws\newpws.csv

```
userID,userIdentity,passwd
201206151300057,John.Doe@contoso.com,pa$$worD1
201206151301452,Tommy.Toe@contoso.com,pa$$worD2
201206151302871,Vince.Voe@contoso.com,pa$$worD3
201206151305021,William.Woe@contoso.com,pa$$worD4
201206151306433,Xerxes.Xoe@contoso.com,pa$$worD5
201206151346790,Yvonne.Yoe@contoso.com,pa$$worD6
```

output csv file: D:\pws\lastprocessedId.csv

```
lastID
201206141186509
```

so far I have this only:

```
import-csv D:\pws\newpws.csv | foreach {

Set-MSOnlineUserPassword -Identity $_.userIdentity -Password $_.passwd -ChangePasswordOnNextLogon:$true -Credential $cred

}
```

I would like to modify this script so it will process only csv lines that:

1. have userID higher than current date time minus 2 hours (rounded to lower hour)  plus ‘00000’ in this format: yyyymmddhh00000 - e.g. if current time is June 15, 2012 3:35PM then filter should include:  201206151300000, **AND**
2. have userID higher than lastID stored in lastprocessedId.csv

after script execution is complete, lastID in lastprocessedId.csv should be updated with the userID of last line in the newpws.csv

Answer (score 1):

You need to stick in a `Where` filter before the `Foreach` stage of the pipeline e.g.:

```
import-csv D:\pws\newpws.csv | 
    where {$_.userID -gt $lastID -and ...} |
    foreach { Set-MSOnlineUserPassword -Identity $_.userIdentity `
              -Password $_.passwd -ChangePasswordOnNextLogon:$true -Credential $cred
}
```